# Getting the JSON data but it's not getting loaded into the view in Ember.js

Tags: codeigniter, rest, ember.js, codeigniter-restserver

I am getting the JSON as per the console but I keep getting this error,

```
Assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key 0 but you have no mapping for it
```

and this error,

```
TypeError {} "Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined"
```

Here's a Sample JSON response,

```
[{"id":"1","last_name":"Solow","first_name":"Jeanne","suffix":null,"expiration":"2013-11-15","email":"jeanne_s@earth.com","street":"16 Ludden Dr.","city":"Austin","state":"TX","zip":"33347","phone":"964-665-8735","interests":"Great Depression,Spanish-American War,Westward movement,Civil Rights,Sports"}, {etc..}
```

Here's my app.js,

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision : 12,
    adapter : DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url : 'http://ankur1.local/index.php/api/example/users/format/json',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
    })
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate : function() {
        this.render('myTemplate', {
            controller : 'Index'
        });
    },
    model : function() {
        return App.myTemplate.find();
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    user : Ember.Object.create({
        name : ""
    }),
    userNameBinding : Ember.Binding.oneWay("this.user.name"),
    clickButton : function(name) {

        if ($("#name").val().trim().length === 0) {
            alert("text box is empty");
        } else {

        }
    }
});

App.myTemplate = DS.Model.extend({
    id : DS.attr('int'),
    last_name : DS.attr('string'),
    first_name : DS.attr('string'),
    suffix : DS.attr('string'),
    expiration : DS.attr('date')
});
```

One point to note I am using Phil Sturgeon's Codeigniter RestServer Library at the backend. What might be wrong with my code or could it be an issue with the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember data requires the json response to be in a certain format. The base key needs to be the name of the model. In your case there is no base key.

Example: You're returning the following

```
[{"id":"1",
  "last_name":"Solow",
  "first_name":"Jeanne",
  "suffix":null,
  "expiration":"2013-11-15",
  "email":"jeanne_s@earth.com",
  "street":"16 Ludden Dr."}, {etc}]
```

but ember needs something like this:

```
{'users': [{"id":"1",
  "last_name":"Solow",
  "first_name":"Jeanne",
  "suffix":null,
  "expiration":"2013-11-15",
  "email":"jeanne_s@earth.com",
  "street":"16 Ludden Dr."}, {etc}]}
```

Either you need to change the json response from the server, or make use of another library for the interface with the server.